deduplicating elements of zmm register?
I'm in a (weird) situation where I have a register containing 8 64-bit pointers, and I need to operate on each unique pointer (the register may rarely contain duplicates). Is there a reasonably performant approach to deduplicating values within a register?

What do you want to do with duplicates? Replace with null? Compress the whole vector?

ah interesting, i think i was exactly looking for those avx512cd instructions

Unless you know something about the input (e.g., it is always sorted/duplicates always neighbor each other), you need 8*9/2 = 36 comparisons at least. I assume with some clever shuffling you can achieve this with 5 vector comparisons and 10 or less shuffles (a trivial solution requiring 7 comparisons and 7 shuffles, would be to 7x cycle the input by one position and compare it to the original) . But combining the results and "deduplicating" will need some more instructions, thus probably even for current Intel CPUs vpconflictq is your best bet.

Do you need to left-pack the unique elements, or is it sufficient to get a mask that's zero for all but one of each set of duplicated elements?  Or what?  Either way you probably want to start with vpconflictq; I think it should be easy to turn the results into a mask.
